# Sum The Sub Query Result

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Example:

```
| date_time           | quantity
-------------------------
| 2017-08-12 09:11:51 | 1
| 2017-08-12 10:12:51 | 1
| 2017-08-12 12:45:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 11:12:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 11:12:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 12:45:51 | 1
| 2017-08-13 13:57:51 | 1
| 2017-08-14 14:23:51 | 1
| 2017-08-14 16:34:51 | 1
| 2017-08-15 16:21:51 | 1
| 2017-08-16 14:31:51 | 1
```

I can get the **result** with this query:

```
SELECT DATE(date_time) as date_time
    ,SUM(quantity) as quantity
FROM report
WHERE date_time BETWEEN '' AND  ''
GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
HAVING SUM(quantity) < 3
```

**Result**:

```
| date_time  | quantity
 -------------
| 2017-08-14 | 2
| 2017-08-15 | 1
| 2017-08-16 | 1
```

I want to SUM quantity afterwards. For example:

```
 quantity
---------
| 4
```

To achieve this I know I need to use the result as sub query to sum afterwards. I tried this but it's wrong:

```
SELECT SUM(topla) FROM (
  ( SELECT DATE(date_time) as date_time
        ,SUM(quantity) as quantity
    FROM report
    WHERE date_time BETWEEN '' AND  ''
    GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
    HAVING SUM(quantity) < 3 
  ) AS topla
)
```

How can I SUM the quantity?

Comment: I cannot replicate any of what's provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to sum the quantity by column name.
(In the example I named it sub_quantity)

Second you do not need to select the date.

So your query could be

```
SELECT SUM(sub_quantity) AS quantity
FROM
  ( SELECT SUM(quantity) AS sub_quantity
   FROM report
   WHERE date_time BETWEEN '' AND ''
   GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
   HAVING SUM(quantity) < 3) a
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the topla with quantity and remove the 'as topla' from the query before topla.

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) total FROM (
  ( SELECT DATE(date_time) as date_time
        ,SUM(quantity) as quantity
    FROM report
    WHERE date_time BETWEEN '' AND  ''
    GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
    HAVING total < 3 
  )
)
```

To use SUM function you have to give column name not the table name.

Comment: I removed the extra brackets and it gives an error:
`error:  Error: ER_DERIVED_MUST_HAVE_ALIAS: Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @ilvthsgm yes, it needs an alias. Give it one